# How to use the PATCH method in HTTP adapters?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Can any please help me about how to make HTTP call using the `PATCH` method in an HTTP Adapter in IBM Worklight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`PATCH` method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) is not supported. Per the [HTTP adapter documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_overview_of_ibm_worklight_adap.html?lang=en):

> You can use the HTTP adapter to send `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` HTTP
> requests and retrieve data from the response body. Data in the
> response can arrive in `XML`, `HTML`, or `JSON` formats.

You can submit feature requests via: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/